# display article names with categories in joomla

Tags: joomla, categories, article

How can i list all the categories of my site with their respective articles? Just wanted to have an image of the category, and the article names by side.

thanks in advance.

Comment: i haven't any, i thought there must be some solution in joomla itself which i am unable to figure out

Comment: in joomla 2.5, i have the option to list all categories, but is there some way i could also display their articles as well?

Comment: I think you get the articles for the deepest category on each branch also. So  depending on your category structure you may b able to override the categories layout. You may also want to play around with the category and categories modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to display all categories including their articles like

category 1

- article
- article
- article

category 2

- article
- article
- article

You'll have to pick a module for that and display one for each category on your frontpage or wherever you want it. 
There are several available in the JED http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news

**Examples are**

News Show Pro GK5

http://www.gavick.com/news-show-pro-gk5.html

JUNewsUltra Pro

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news/17771

JA Bulletin

http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/extensions/ja-bulletin-module